# $\sigma(\sigma(p^2)) \neq 2p^2$ for all odd primes $p$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How to prove that $\sigma(\sigma(p^2)) \neq 2p^2$ for all odd primes $p$?

I know that $\sigma(p^2)=1+p+p^2$ but I can't progress anymore.

Comment: This is actually false for $p=2$.  I'm guessing you mean to restrict to odd primes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider $p \geq 11$, and assume on the contrary that $\sigma(\sigma(p^2))=\sigma(1+p+p^2)=2p^2$.

If $1+p+p^2$ has at least 3 distinct prime factors $q, r, s$, then write $1+p+p^2=q^ar^bs^cm$, then $2p^2=\sigma(1+p+p^2)=\sigma(q^a)\sigma(r^b)\sigma(s^c)\sigma(m)$. If $p \nmid \sigma(q^a)$, then since $\sigma(q^a) \mid 2p^2$, we have $\sigma(q^a) \mid 2$, so $2 \geq \sigma(q^a)=1+q+ \ldots +q^a \geq 3$, a contradiction. Thus $p \mid \sigma(q^a)$. Similarly $p \mid \sigma(q^b), \sigma(s^c)$, so $p^3 \mid \sigma(q^a)\sigma(r^b)\sigma(s^c)\sigma(m)=2p^2$, a contradiction.

Therefore we have $1+p+p^2=q^ar^b, q \not =r, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ or $1+p+p^2=q^a, a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $q, r$ are primes. Note that $1+p+p^2$ is odd, so $q, r$ must be odd.

Let us first consider $1+p+p^2=q^ar^b$. Then $2p^2=\sigma(1+p+p^2)=\sigma(q^a)\sigma(r^b)$. As above, if $p \nmid \sigma(q^a)$, we have $\sigma(q^a) \mid 2$, so $2 \geq \sigma(q^a) \geq 3$, a contradiction. Therefore $p \mid \sigma(q^a)$, and similarly $p \mid \sigma(r^b)$. WLOG assume $\sigma(q^a) \leq \sigma(r^b)$, so that we have $$p=\sigma(q^a)=1+q+ \ldots +q^a, 2p=\sigma(r^b)=1+r+ \ldots +r^b$$

If $r \not =3$, then $r \geq 5, q \geq 3$, so

$$p=\frac{q^a-1}{q-1}+q^a \leq \frac{q^a-1}{2}+q^a, 2p=\frac{r^b-1}{r-1}+r^b \leq \frac{r^b-1}{4}+r^b$$

$$2p+1 \leq 3q^a, 8p+1 \leq 5r^b$$

$$(2p+1)(8p+1) \leq 15q^ar^b=15(1+p+p^2)$$

$$p^2-5p-14 \leq 0$$

However $p^2-5p-14 \geq 11p-5p-14=6p-14>0$, a contradiction.

Therefore $r=3$, so $q \not =3$, so $q \geq 5$. We have

$$1+p+p^2=q^a3^b, p=\frac{q^a-1}{q-1}+q^a \leq \frac{q^a-1}{4}+q^a, 2p=1+3+ \ldots +3^b=\frac{3^b-1}{2}+3^b$$

$$4p+1 \leq 5q^a, 4p+1 \leq 3(3^b)$$

$$(4p+1)^2 \leq 15(q^a3^b)=15(1+p+p^2)$$

$$p^2-7p-14 \leq 0$$

However $p^2-7p-14 \geq 11p-7p-14=4p-14>0$, a contradiction.

Therefore we are left with the case $1+p+p^2=q^a$, where $q \geq 3$ is an odd prime. Then $$2p^2=\sigma(q^a)=1+q+ \ldots +q^a=\frac{q^a-1}{q-1}+q^a \leq \frac{q^a-1}{2}+q^a$$

$$4p^2+1 \leq 3q^a=3(1+p+p^2)$$

$$p^2-3p-2 \leq 0$$

However $p^2-3p-2 \geq 11p-3p-2=8p-2>0$, a contradiction.

Therefore $\sigma(\sigma(p^2)) \not =2p^2$ for $p \geq 11$.

It remains to check $p=3, 5$, or $7$. We have:

$$\sigma(\sigma(3^2))=\sigma(13)=14 \not =2(3^2)$$
$$\sigma(\sigma(5^2))=\sigma(31)=32 \not =2(5^2)$$
$$\sigma(\sigma(7^2))=\sigma(57)=\sigma(3)\sigma(19)=80 \not =2(7^2)$$

Therefore $\sigma(\sigma(p^2)) \not =2p^2$ for all odd primes $p$.